# How to stop checking for variadic arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have a class that contains a vector of a specific type, and I want to give it a variadic constructor that adds elements to the vector.

```
class MyClass
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    MyClass(int &x...)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, x);
        while(/*some condition, I'm not sure*/)
        {
            numbers.push_back(va_arg(args, int));
        }
        va_end(args);
    }
};
```

How do I know when to stop checking for arguments? Is my variadic syntax even correct? All I had to go on was the variadic functions tutorial on cppreference.com.

Comment: Simple answer: You can't know.  That's why you have to have a scheme of some sort of determining the last item.  Either by a sentinel value,  another parameter that tells you the number of arguments, or use the technique that `printf` uses, and that is the format string describes the parameters to look for.

Comment: So perhaps something like: `MyClass(int num_of_args, int &...)` ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't even think you can have a reference argument as the parameter before the `...`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Sure, you can.  You can have anything you want before the `...`, as long as there is a `,` before the `...` to separate them.  You cannot qualifyy the `...` itself with a type, and you cannot use a `...` with `va_start()` without another parameter before `...` as a reference point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Isn't there something in the standard mentioning what types of arguments can be placed before the `...`?  I could have sworn that references were forbidden.

Comment: @KaiSchmidt: change `MyClass(int num_of_args, int &...)` to `MyClass(int num_of_args, ...)` to do something like that.  Then you can call `va_arg(int)` in a loop for `num_of_arg` iterations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: AFAIK, there is no restriction on reference parameters appearing before the `...`, nor does it make sense to have such a restriction anyway, IMHO.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If I do that, should I then change the arguments of `va_start` to `va_start(args, num_of_args)` ?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but in C++, you can also use variadic templates instead of C ellipses to achieve that goal (in which case the syntax is a bit different, it also looks a bit like your "int&...", I wouldn't be surprised if you saw variadic templates and C ellipses then confused both)

Comment: @KaiSchmidt: yes.  When you call `va_start()`, you have to specify the last named parameter that immediately precedes the `...`. That is the starting point where `va_arg()` starts reading data from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - In the standard, check 18.7.3 (Other Runtime Support). `* The parameter parmN is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list of the function definition (the one just before the ...).
If the parameter parmN is declared with a function, array, **or reference type**, or with a type that is not compatible with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: @Caninonos: in C++11, you can write the constructor to accept a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) so objects can be initialized using a *braced-init-list*, ie: `MyClass cls{1, 2, 3};`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right, that's even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use C-style variable argument lists unless you somehow tell the function how many arguments it gets. For example, you could pass an `int count` as the first argument to the variable argument list and use this count to determine when to stop processing arguments. Functions like `printf()` use the format string to determine how many arguments to expect (and what type they got).

The easiest way to give your class a variable number of arguments is not to use variable argument lists but rather to use an `std:initializer_list<int>`:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    MyClass(std::initializer_list<int> args): v(args) {}
};
```

It could be used like this:

```
MyClass object1{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
MyClass object2({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

If you mean to use a variadic template, the notation for the constructor would be something like this:

```
template <typename... T>
MyClass(T&&... args): v{ std::forward<T>(args)... } {}
```

However, this may do something subtly different. I'd suggest to go with the `std::initializer_list<int>`.